# How to make new model with some fields of other models by inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, oop

<I have two classes with too many fields . which are basically the Model of MVC  . I want to create a third class which take few fields from both 1st,2nd by inheritance but not  all the fields of 1st and 2nd class is it possible by inheritance .I want to
make a new class without declare field in it

````
 public class OpeningBalanceLiteModel
    {
        public Int64 LedgerId { get; set; }
        public String LedgerCode { get; set; }
        public Int64? ParentLedgerId { get; set; }
   
        public Decimal OpeningBalance { get; set; }
        public Boolean? Status { get; set; }
        public Int32? LedgerCategoryId { get; set; }
        
        public Byte Is_Active { get; set; }
        public Byte Is_Deleted { get; set; }
    }
    public class DrCrDetailLiteModel
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public Int32 TransactionTypeId { get; set; }

        public Int32? AmountType { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public String VoucherNarration { get; set; }
     
        public Int32 FinancialYearId { get; set; }
        public Int64 CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Decimal? SubsidiaryId { get; set; }
        public Decimal? LocationBranchId { get; set; }
        public Decimal? DivisionId { get; set; }
        public Int32? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Int32? ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Int32? ProjectEstimationId { get; set; }
       
        public Boolean? IsAdvancePayment { get; set; }
        public Boolean? IsHiddenFromSourceLedger { get; set; }
        public Boolean? IsReversed { get; set; }
    }
    public class OpeningBalanceDrCrMurg
    {

    }```


* i wan to add 3 fields of both class by inheritance
````

Answer (score 2):

you should create a Base Class ex:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id1 { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
    public int Id3 { get; set; }

}





 public class childrenClass1 :BaseClass
    {
        ...

    }



  public class childrenClass2:BaseClass
    {
        ...

    }
```

Now children class1 and 2 have Id1/Id2/Id3

Answer (score 2):

We commonly calls inheritance a "is a" relation ship, an apple **is a** fruit. If you do not include all properties it is not a "is a" relationship. Is all fruits have a color, then an apple **must** have a color.

Moreover, c# does not support multiple inheritance. You could inherit from multiple *interfaces*, and that would also allow you to use [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to *hide* properties unless a reference of the interface type is used. But I get the impression that your goal is *implementation inheritance*.

My recommendation would be to use Composition instead of inheritance. Group your properties in to logical groups, and compose these models, for example:

```
public class LedgerModel{
        public Int64 LedgerId { get; set; }
        public String LedgerCode { get; set; }
        public Int64? ParentLedgerId { get; set; }
}
public class OpeningBalanceLiteModel{
     LedgerModel {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

That should allow finer grained control to allow you to include any combination of property-groups in your classes.